# Laravel Trying to get property 'image' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

All pages worked fine. After deleting 4 products from admin panel I've got error:

```
Laravel Trying to get property 'image' of non-object
```

How can I check if this page have no items or other suggestions?

Actually, it is my problem for 1 week and I am really need help

card.blade.php:

```
  <img src="{{($sku->product->image) }}" alt="{{ $sku->product->__('name') }}">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3>{{ $sku->product->__('name') }}</h3>
            @isset($sku->product->properties)
                @foreach ($sku->propertyOptions as $propertyOption)
                    <h4>{{ $propertyOption->property->__('name') }}: {{ $propertyOption->__('name') }}</h4>
                @endforeach
            @endisset
```

Sku:

```
class Sku extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'count', 'price'];
    protected $visible = ['id', 'count', 'price', 'product_name'];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
```

Product:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, Translatable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'code', 'price', 'category_id', 'description', 'image', 'hit', 'new', 'recommend', 'count', 'name_en',
        'description_en'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function skus()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sku::class);
    }

    public function properties()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class, 'property_product')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

MainController:

```
public function index(ProductsFilterRequest $request)
   {
       $skusQuery = Sku::with(['product', 'product.category']);

       if ($request->filled('price_from')) {
           $skusQuery->where('price', '>=', $request->price_from);
       }

       if ($request->filled('price_to')) {
           $skusQuery->where('price', '<=', $request->price_to);
       }

       $skus = $skusQuery->paginate(6)->withPath("?".$request->getQueryString());

       return view('index', compact('skus'));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you call a relationship data make sure you check with null coalescing. So, if someone delete a data or failed to load the eloquent relation it doesn't break the system. You can do that by following this:

```
{{$data->relation?$data->relation->property:''}}
```

You can also try this alternative method

```
@if($data->relation)
//here are the properties you are tring to get
<span>{{$data->relation->name}}</span>
<span>{{$data->relation->phone}}</span>
@endif
```

In your case you can do these

```
  <img src="{{($sku->product?$sku->product->image:'') }}" alt="{{ $sku->product?$sku->product->__('name'):'' }}">
    <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{ $sku->product?$sku->product->__('name'):'' }}</h3>
        @isset($sku->product->properties)
            @foreach ($sku->propertyOptions as $propertyOption)
                <h4>{{ $propertyOption->property->__('name') }}: {{ $propertyOption->__('name') }}</h4>
            @endforeach
        @endisset
```

Comment: Thanks! it works but here is another problem

Comment: @amir what's that

Comment: Trying to get property 'code' of non-object

Comment: And I can't make it like you've suggested here is an error

Comment: Please share the screenshots & detailed problem